# cassie dependency with cassandra 2.0.1 and scala 2.10.2

Tags: scala, cassandra, sbt

I want to use cassie client for using cassandra 2.0.1 with scala 2.10.2 . so i want to know which dependency i have to put in sbt for using it.

```
"com.twitter" % "cassie" % "0.19.0"
```

this is unresolved dependency. tell me the correct version .

Comment: Just a quick question. Are you committed to using Cassie? It hasn't been touched in almost a year. There are other options. https://github.com/twitter/cassie

Comment: can u suggest me which client i should use with scala because datastax is giving very slow speed and i think its not reliable.And if i use hector it is giving me some trouble because it is built on java.

Comment: Haha uh oh. Those are the two options I was going to mention. I'm surprised you are seeing slowness with Datastax. And both Datastax and Hector are written in Java, so there should be no issue in Scala.

Comment: ok . can we use all the functionality of cassandra with datastax

Comment: I am unaware of anything it can't do. Check for yourself: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/webhelp/index.html#common/drivers/reference/driverReference_r.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to retrieve the client is [not complete documented](https://github.com/twitter/cassie#lets-get-this-party-started).

Add this to your build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Twitter's Repository" at "http://maven.twttr.com/"

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "cassie" % "0.19.0" excludeAll(
        ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
        ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
        ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
    )
```

There is already a [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/cassie/pull/5) to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody stumbling on this, the twitter client is outdated and a pain to build in recent scala versions, furthermore the newer cassandra clients use CQL and thrift is deprecated. So I would recommend using the java datastaxx driver for a smooth sailing, and forget about cassie.